# Monotouch - Unable to update the UI on Animation Completion

Tags: ios, animation, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I got a problem on the completion handler of my animation. I'm trying to bring up a UILabel to display the state of the loading. The state is updated in the Init() method.

The problem is that the Label (loadingLabel) appears at the end of the Init() instead of at the end of the animation.

Thank you

Here is my code:

```
AnimationManager.BounceAppear (
    this.logoImage, 
    duration: 0.5, 
    delay: 1,
    onFinished:
        () => {

        this.loadingLabel.Hidden = false;

        // Long Process which update loadingLabel
        Init (); 

        }
);

public static void BounceAppear(UIView view, double delay = 0.5, double duration = 0.3, Action onFinished = null)
{
    double interval = duration/ 2.0f;
    view.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.001f, 0.001f);
    UIView.AnimationWillEnd += () => {

    };
    UIView.Animate(
        interval,
        delay,
        UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear,
        ()=>
        {
        view.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);
        },
        ()=> 
        {
        UIView.Animate(
            interval,
            ()=> view.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.9f,0.9f),
            ()=> 
            {
            UIView.Animate(
                interval,
                ()=> view.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity(),
                ()=> { if(onFinished != null){ onFinished(); }} );
        }
    );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say yourself, Init() is a long process. As such, it blocks the UI.

So, make sure the Init() method is ran asynchronously, and you should be fine.

Comment: But i set Hidden = false before the call to Init().

Comment: that's not important. you have no guarantee it'll be shown. At first, you could move the Hidden = false INSIDE of the animation loop, but that's not a valid solution as Init() will still freeze your app which is really really really bad